# How do I ignore the titlesec package, and create a subsection without runin?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, titlesec, layout

I'm using the titlesec package to have runin subsection titles. However, I only want this some of the time, and if I try to break the line with \ it either throws an error to adds some weird indentation. Can anyone help?

```
% Inline subsection
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]% runin puts it in the same paragraph
        {\bfseries}% formatting commands to apply to the whole heading
        {\thesubsection}% the label and number
        {0.5em}% space between label/number and subsection title
        {\large}% formatting commands applied just to subsection title
        []% punctuation or other commands following subsection title
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a strange requirement. Anyway, here's how you can do.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]% runin puts it in the same paragraph
        {\bfseries}% formatting commands to apply to the whole heading
        {\thesubsection}% the label and number
        {0.5em}% space between label/number and subsection title
        {}% formatting commands applied just to subsection title
        []% punctuation or other commands following subsection title

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\psubsection}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\subsection*{#3}}{\subsection[#2]{#3}}%
  \mbox{}\par\nopagebreak\@afterheading
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\subsection{Run in}
Some text

\psubsection{Not run in}
Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed `\large`, because it would be unsightly with run-in titles.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
\subsubsection{My header (singled out)}
\paragraph{}\noindent
% paragraph
```

If you use it often, you can put it into a command

`\newcommand{\singlesubsec}[1]{\subsection{#1}\paragraph{}\noindent}`

which you would then use (to replace the above) as

```
\singlesubsec{My header (singled out)}
% paragraph
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Inline subsection
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]% runin puts it in the same paragraph
        {\bfseries}% formatting commands to apply to the whole heading
        {\thesubsection}% the label and number
        {0.5em}% space between label/number and subsection title
        {\large}% formatting commands applied just to subsection title
        []% punctuation or other commands following subsection title
        
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
        
\begin{document}

    \subsection{Header in-line}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \subsection{Header on own}
    \paragraph{}\noindent
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]